# Jrebel fails on loading place holders in Spring MVC

Tags: jrebel

I have a modular spring mvc app, say MyProject. MyProject is dependent on a few other projects, that are included as pom dependencies. MyProject has a few spring config files with respect to application, security etc. The security related spring config file has the login/logout stuff. Most of these values are place holders from properties defined within that same xml config file. Whenever I change something in a class, jrebel reloads that class but then complains about placeholders in my spring config file and gives errors :

```
Could not instantiate bean class [MyAPP.MyCustomLogoutSuccessHandler]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character '{' for PATH in "MyAPPContextName/${loginUrlPath}"
```

And the spring config entry is of style :

```
<bean id="myLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="MyApp.MyCustomLogoutSuccessHandler">
            <constructor-arg ref="rootAppUrl"/>

        <constructor-arg value="${loginUrlPath}"/>
        ....
```

All I am asking jrebel to do is to be able to reload class changes of MyProject, but it hasnt been able to. I have posted this on [jrebel's support forum](http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/topic/jrebel-not-starting-up/) without too much of help. I have even tried to upgrade to your nightly build version of 5.5.5 still no luck. What can I do to fix this (without being able to send a hello world app to jrebel !!)? What can I really do to pay you and use your software ?

Comment: have you reported this to JRebel support? http://zeroturnaround.com/forums/

Comment: @AntonArhipov If you had read the link I posted in my question above (jrebel's support forum), you would have come to know that am already going back and forth with your support. However, I'd like a solution - "without being able to send a hello world app to jrebel !!)"

Comment: Sorry, missed the link. Well, you are asking to fix something in a black box and through unofficial channel. JRebel has support for property placeholders in Spring but you have probably hit a corner case for that integration with a clever application structure. We'd like to help, but there's some debugging involved.